# Passenger (mod-rails) can't find libopenssl-ruby

Tags: 11.10, ruby, rails, nginx

Trying to build an [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) server with [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) on Ubuntu 11.10 (hurray for the new version!).  Running "passenger-install-nginx-module" outputs the following error:

```
* OpenSSL support for Ruby... not found
```

With the following suggestion to fix it:

```
* To install OpenSSL support for Ruby:
  Please run apt-get install libopenssl-ruby as root.
```

Running "sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby" yields the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libruby' instead of 'libopenssl-ruby'
libruby is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

A little research shows that libruby is a virtual package that provides libopenssl-ruby as part of the package.  However, the passenger-install-nginx-module script still can't find it, and keeps throwing the same error.  Help me, please!  I'm in a little over my head on this one, and the google-the-error-code method that usually works is failing me today.

Comment: I'll try to confirm this, I'm upgrading my Rails server to 11.10 later today.

Comment: OK, I can't replicate this. :(

Answer (score 7):

You need to change to your ruby `ext/openssl/` directory, then run

```
ruby extconf.rb 
make
make install
```

then try `passenger-install-nginx-module` again

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My computer has died in the interim, so I'm waiting for the replacement to arrive. I'll test this out when it gets in.

Comment: @flintinatux did you get the chance to test it again?

Comment: Had the same problem as the asker, but with the Blather gem. Tried your instructions but extconf.rb didn't work ("Makefile wasn't created"). I found a forum post that helped - http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/99825 - and now these instructions work.

Answer (score -1):

No. I got so mad at Ubuntu that I switched to Windows 7. I realized that I was spending more time setting up tools than I was actually producing code. I've since moved on to other projects, and still only use Windows 7.